# Cannot add event listener with Javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, mouseover

I am far from being an expert in these matters, and I am trying to use `addEventListener` to replace the `onlick`, `onmouseover` etc. which previously I had in the HTML itself (`<span id='' onClick='' etc.>`). This was all working fine.  I have an `initializePage()` function.  This rest of the code inside this function still works.  There are no issues with elements not defined at the time the function ss called.  At the top of this function I have inserted the code to add an event listener. In the code below I give a sample ID - I'm just trying to get it to work for ONE element first.

```
function initializePage() {

  document.getElementById('region-africa').addEventListener("mouseover", highlightItem);
  (rest of initializePage code here - it's all fine - no issues)
}
```

The `highlightItem` function is as follows:

```
function highlightItem() {
  console.log("I am here");
  this.style.fontSize = "1.1em";
  this.style.fontStyle = "italic";
  this.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  this.style.background = "white";
  this.style.cursor = "pointer";
  this.style.border = "2px solid blue";
}
```

Nothing happens.  No message is output to the console log.  Nothing.  And as far as I can see from the developer tools the listener is not even being added to the element.

I've tried different permutations of the syntax ( `() => {}` when adding the event listener etc.).  Nothing seems to work.  I'm expecting this to work as it did previously when this was defined in the HTML.

Comment: do you mind adding a sample [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/web-platform) replicating your issue?

Comment: if this did work earlier when directly added to the HTML, are you now sure that `document.getElementById('region-africa')` is returning the element you want to manipulate? The key is to make sure that this script is being run after the dom has rendered this element. You can do this by moving the script tag to the end of the body

Comment: Sidenote: don't set all those `style` properties. _Never_ set styles directly, keep your CSS on the CSS side by instead setting `element.classList.add("some-class-name")` and now all those rules can live as normal CSS in your stylesheet, and are "just more CSS" instead of html-level overrides inaccessibly wrapped in JS. Want to change the look? Just update your CSS instead of updating JavaScript, which has nothing to do with styling.

Comment: Re the above comments: 1. I have checked the source to ensure the id is valid and occurs only once and is the same element that the onmouseover was attached to previously.  2. Thanks for the tip about using CSS.  I will certainly do this,  Now you mention it, I realise this is probably the best approach in this case.  However, there are other cases where CSS will not suffice and I'd like to learn how to add event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

I've identified the issue. After creating an event listener for `id item1`, I was then executing the following command:

```js
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = document.getElementById("list1").innerHTML
```

Here, list1 contained item1 as an element. This works fine when the event listeners are defined directly in the HTML, but not when they are added using JavaScript.

My solution is to avoid creating separate lists like list1, list2, etc. Instead, I'll create a single list and hide/unhide items depending on the option selected.

I've also noticed some similar oddities when updating innerHTML, e.g. Some text, then if I overwrite the innerHTML of "conainer" with "Some text", the id item1 still seems to exist unless it is explicitly removed.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
function highlightItem(e) {
  console.log("I am here");
  e.target.style.fontSize = "1.1em";
  e.target.style.fontStyle = "italic";
  e.target.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  e.target.style.background = "white";
  e.target.style.cursor = "pointer";
  e.target.style.border = "2px solid blue";
}
```

In your original version `this` wouldn't refer to the element. You would need to get the event argument, and then grab its `target` property, in order to get a reference to the target element.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this.  It;'s why I added the line console.log("I am here").  It doesn't even get that far.  My approach has been to first get it to do something, anything and then worry about how to correctly reference the elements in the remainder of the code.